# FTP copy failure depending on number and size of files

Tags: powershell, ftp

I need to copy several files on several ftps.

I use [this](https://gist.github.com/3993539) Write-FTP function. Various versions of it circulate around on the net and SO.

The problem is that copy fails depending on number of files and other statements. Here is the test code:

```
. ".\Write-FTP.ps1"

$ftp = "ftp://10.35.3.66//var/www/html/"

$files=@()
@(1..151) | %{ $files += "File1.zip"}

ForEach( $file in $files) {
        $file
        Write-Ftp  $file $ftp @("user", "pass")
        #[System.GC]::Collect()
}
```

On my system 150 files will work, but 151st will issue error. If I uncomment GC.Collect, it fails after 3 files. File1.zip is empty zip file. Here is the output:

```
---------- PowerShell ----------
File1.zip
File1.zip
File1.zip
Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server r
eturned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized."
At D:\Work\ISPPlus\_novi\Write-FTP.ps1:17 char:30
+         $rs = $ftp.GetRequestStream <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The error occurs depending on size and number of files. It looks like some memory issue or something, but I can't find whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/4acf763a-b788-4131-90d7-61b18546909b).

In particular case of the above mentioned test file what passed was to create credential object in advance:

```
$cr = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("aplikacija", "aplikacija")
ForEach( $file in $files) {
        $file
        Write-Ftp $file $ftp $cr
}
```

Setting KeepAlive option of FtpWebRequest to false also worked.